# SQL time difference and group by 3 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table where I want to calculate the total time spent by each person, i.e time difference group by 3 columns.  The table looks like:

[image]

I want the output something like this:

[image]

I can group by say per_1 but not all together.

```
SELECT per_1, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)) / 3600 AS Duration 
FROM os 
GROUP BY per_1
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2), you can confident that your schema design is suboptimal. Fix that, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema doesn't look right to me. Still, you can achieve the same results with `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT Person, SUM(Duration)
FROM (
         SELECT per_1 AS Person, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) / 3600 AS Duration
         FROM os
         WHERE per_1 IS NOT NULL AND per_1 <> ''

         UNION ALL

         SELECT per_2 AS Person, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) / 3600 AS Duration
         FROM os
         WHERE per_2 IS NOT NULL AND per_2 <> ''

         UNION ALL

         SELECT per_3 AS Person, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) / 3600 AS Duration
         FROM os
         WHERE per_3 IS NOT NULL AND per_3 <> ''
     ) AS derived
GROUP BY Person
ORDER BY SUM(Duration) DESC;
```